# Revert git repository to prior commit using Github GUI

Tags: github

While there is loads of information available on how to revert to a specific commit using the `git` command line - e.g. [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Is there a way to achieve same using the `github` gui? There *is* a feature to revert the *latest* commit.  However I was unable to find options from the `Commits history` to revert to a specific commit in the list:

[image: When we click on the commit hash button] on the right and here is what we see:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhu]

so there is no feature shown here for `Revert to this commit`.

Comment: It is worth noting that when using the gui you can right click on a repo and open a git command line for that repo, in case you need to do something the gui doesn't surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can press the button on the side `< >` (like in your first picture) and with this you can browse the repository at the time after this commit. Now you can create a pull request or you can download the repository at this very point in time.

I guess there is no other solution if you really want to achieve this in the browser. In GitHub desktop there is the `Revert` button for each of your commits (screenshot).

[image: Revert button]

Answer (score 2):

Jump to the PR which is included in the commit which is to be reverted. Go to conversation section, there you will see revert option in front of all commits included in that PR ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41t0V.png))